# Bulk change file names in a directory - Shell

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-14.04, counter, file-rename

I tried to find something close to what I need, but ended up with bits and pieces from many questions here, and, obviously, my code doesn't work.

I've never programmed anything by myself, and have close to zero knowledge in programming.

What I'm trying to do, is to rename a bunch of files I have in 2 different directories, so that files in both have the same name, **with no space chars**.

For example:

> ~/Documents/Dir1/1.pdf instead of: ~/Documents/Dir1/file A.pdf
>
> ~/Documents/Dir2/1.pdf instead of: ~/Documents/Dir2/file A.pdf

This was the extent of my abilities:

```
#!/bin/bash

b4file=$1
c=0

for i in $b4file do
  c=$((c+1))
  pref=$(printf "%03d" $c)
  mv "$i" "${pref}|$i"
done
```

The error I get is

> mv.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `c=$((c+1))'
>
> mv.sh: line 7: `  c=$((c+1))'

Answer (score 0):

For loop read files one by one so use below code , this will remove your error. 
    #!/bin/bash
    b4file=$1
    c=0

```
for i in $b4file/* do
  c=$((c+1))
  pref=$(printf "%03d" $c)
  mv "$i" "${pref}|$i"
done
```